# PyQt emit signal with dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I wanna to emit signal that is defined:

```
finished = pyqtSignal(dict)

# other place it's connected to function:
def finised(self, dict_result):
```

I call it `self.finished.emit({"bk": {}})` and it works.
Now I call it with `self.finished.emit({2: {}})`and it don't work!!

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/sylwek/workspace/t2-pv/Manager.py", line 452, in run
>       self.finished.emit({2: {}})
>   TypeError: TesterManager.finished[dict].emit(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'dict'

Is it normal? I can change `{2: {}}` to `{'2': {}}` but I would like to understand why and be sure there will be no other surprises!

I use PyQt 5.8.2-2 and python 3.6.1-1

#### EDIT (add working example):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class Emiterer(QtCore.QThread):
    f = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Emiterer, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.f.emit({"2": {}})
        # self.f.emit({2: {}})  < == this don't work!


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.e = Emiterer()
        self.e.f.connect(self.finised)
        self.e.start()

    def finised(self, r_dict):
        print(r_dict)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Main()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Surprisingly, it works for Python-2.7 with PyQt4. If it doesn't work for PyQt5, I expect it's a bug.

Comment: It probably worked in the past.. But I am not sure.. Where I can give information about this bug? Can sb else confirm that have the same bug as I?

Comment: Someone recently [reported the same issue](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2017-May/039166.html) on the PyQt mailinglist FWIW.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `object` instead of `dict` in the `pyqtSignal` definition. E.g.

```
class Emiterer(QtCore.QThread):
    f = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
```

The reason for this is that signals defined as `pyqtSignal(dict)` are actually interpreted the same as `pyqtSignal('QVariantMap')` by PyQt5 and QVariantMap can only have strings as keys.

You can check this (for your specific class) with

```
m = Emiterer.staticMetaObject
method = m.method(m.methodCount() - 1)  # the last defined signal or slot
print(method.methodSignature())
```

This would print `PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'f(QVariantMap)')`

Comment: Thank you as soon as I test it. I will check as the answer.